# Fixing up the postdoc treatment question

Tags: discussion

How can we fix [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/842/should-a-postdoc-obey-when-is-asked-to-do-things-she-knows-little-about) to be more focused on helping postdocs and less argumentative and provocative?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an easy way to clean up this question. The premise is argumentative, and therefore the responses (including my own) have a somewhat strident tone as well. The comments don't really help.

We shouldn't delete the question—but perhaps the issue is to clean up the header of the question to be less "angry?"

Answer (score 1):

I think the title of the question should be changed, the "obey" is not really constructive. Perhaps the problem comes from the fact that in some fields and in some places, the term "postdoc" can correspond to different kind of positions.

Somehow, I have the feeling that this question concerns the tradeoff between:

- the fact that the postdoc wants to work on his personal research, and wants to do things that he is interested in.
- the fact that the PI who hired the postdoc wants him to do things that the funding requires, and that it can involve some non-research tasks.

Ideally, they should both converge, but in practice, it might not be the case. So, the question could be how to find a decent tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

Delete it.

It's not going to contribute anything useful, it's not constructive, and the site's better off without it.

Comment: I have to agree.